# How to know what a tap has been made on a header section of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have sometimes a header section (just one as I have only one section). I added a gesture (single tap) like the following:

```
let singleTap = UIShortTapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTap:")
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
tableView.headerViewForSection(0)?.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

It works. The problem is that when my tableView has just a few rows, if I tap below the last row (on a blank space), it triggers the gesture as well.

How to avoid it? I was thinking a way might be to check if the location of the tap is within the bounds of the header but I don't know how to do it.

For a normal row it's easy, I just use `tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point: CGPoint)` but what about for a header?

**EDIT:**

It seems I need to register my header to get something when I call `tableView.headerViewForSection(0)` but the problem is that my header is an `UIView`, not a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` or `UITableViewCell` so I cannot register it (I think...).

It was working so far because I added the gesture on the table view as well.

So as the gesture is added on the whole tableView, when I get the view from the gesture, I get the tableView and not the header.

So what I've done is get the header from the tableView using its tag:

```
let header = tableView.viewWithTag(Tag.Header.rawValue)
```

and then check the location of the tap if it is inside the header view:

```
let location = sender.locationInView(sender.view)
if header!.pointInside(location, withEvent: nil) { ... }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible better approach is to set the gestureRecognizer on the mainView of the viewController (the tableView) and to detect the tapped view in the gestureRecognizer's gesture action:

```
{
    let singleTap = UIShortTapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTap:")
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)  // <--
}
...

@IBAction func singleTap(tapGestureRecognizer: UIShortTapGestureRecognizer) {
    // detect the tapped view
    var loc = tapGestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.tableView)

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(tableView.headerViewForSection(0)?.frame, loc)) {
        // header was tapped
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: As I explained in my edit, I kinda used your way except to retrieve the header as it seems I need to register it but cannot do it.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to do this is to just attach the listener when the table notifies you (via `UITableViewDelegate`) it is about to display a header:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let singleTap = // setup gesture

    // Add gesture to already created header
    view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
}
```

Then you can just setup the selector function:

```
func singleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let headerView = gesture.view
    // Do something with header view
}
```

Comment: In my case, the problem is I use the same gesture for the whole tableView, so I couldn't find out if the gesture.view is the headerView without a tag (or maybe using a global variable for the headerView)

Comment: Ah, got it. Well if you have more issues let us know, but glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 3):

Try to add Tag for your HeaderView.

```
-(void) selectheader:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    UIView *headerView = gestureRecognizer.view;
      if (headerView.tag) {

       }
}
```

And

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    view.tag = section;
 // add your gesture 
    return view;
}
```

Comment: How? I mean adding the tag on the headerView ok but how do I make the match with the UITapGestureRecognizer as this one doesn't have a tag?

Comment: It couldn't really work this way (as explained in my update) because of my header cannot be register. But thanks for the idea of the tag

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution I came up with was to create different targets on a button inside the `viewForHeaderInSection` method based on the section. I am using a button but this should work just as well with UITapGestureRecognizer

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        // ...

        if section == 0 {
            cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(firstSectionTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        } else if section == 1 {
            cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(secondSectionTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        // ...

}
```

Then in the ViewController:

```
@objc func goalCategoryTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
    print("Section One Tapped")
}

@objc func ideaCategoryTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
    print("Section Two Tapped")
}
```